# Is that possible to get the current context from the non-activity class

Tags: android

I am quite new to Android. In my project, I need to get the context of the current activity which is running, from the Non-activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `Context` as local variable in non activity class and set this variable from activity from calling constructor like

```
public class NonActivity {
    private Context context;
    public NonActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

and create instance of that class from your activity like

```
NonActivity instance = new NonActivity(CurrentActivity.this);
```

**Edit 1 :: To Check Context Is From Which Activity**

Check in `NonActivity` class if it is from the activity where you want the request from like following

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
if(activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(YourActivity.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
    // it is from the class you want.
} else {
    // not from class
}
```

hope it'll work.

Comment: the thing is, I just want to place a condition whether it is in the same activity where I come from or else in the different activity. I found an optional solution but just want to clarify.